# Is my application commercial according to this definition?

Tags: internet, software, business, terms-of-service, open-source-software

I'm planing to use [the Imgur API](http://api.imgur.com) in my own application. According to their document(emphasis mine):

> **Commercial Usage**
>
> Your application is commercial if you're making any money with it
>   (which includes in-app advertising), *if you plan on making any money
>   with it*, or if it belongs to a commercial organization. To use
>   Imgur's API commercially, ......
>
> **Free Usage**
>
> The Imgur API is free for non-commercial usage. Your application is
>   probably free if you don't plan on making any money with it, *or if
>   it's open source.*

The problem is that I do expect some money from it: there is a "donate" button on every page. However, I'm also willing to make my application open source.

So my question is: Should I pay for commercially using the Imgur API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The license terms are quite clear, in one place. They define "commercial" as the intent to make *any* money from the app. Having a donate button does not negate the intent to make some money. They murk things up by saying "Your application is **probably** free if you don't plan on making any money with it, or if it's open source". But that is not a promise of a license term, it is a suggestion. If the app were non-commercial, then use is free; if it is open source, you may negotiate with them.